# Group by calculation based on LAG

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am exploring some possibilities of SQL (MS SQL) and was wondering if someone can give me some advice with the following question.

I have two tables, one that contains person data and one that contains inquiry data of a person.

When I run the following query, I get the result as shown in the table below.

```
SELECT Person.Id, Inquiry.Id, Inquiry.StartDate, Inquiry.EndDate, DATEDIFF(DAY, Inquiry.StartDate, Inquiry.EndDate) AS Duration, LAG(Inquiry.EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Person.Id ORDER BY Inquiry.StartDate) AS EndDatePreviousFile, DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(Inquiry.EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Person.Id ORDER BY Inquiry.StartDate), Inquiry.StartDate) AS DateDiffStartPreviousEnd 
FROM Person INNER JOIN Inquiry ON Person.Id = Inquiry.PersonId
WHERE Person.Id = 1
ORDER BY Inquiry.StartDate
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, I use the window function 'LAG' to get the end date of the previous inquiry, so I can calculate the difference between the start date of the current record and the end date of the previous record.

Next I would like to group this data, but only when the above mentioned difference (start date current record and end date previous record) is smaller than 15 days, so I can then calculate the total of the duration of the grouped records.

Grouping by the result of a window function is not possible, but perhaps there are other ways to accomplish this.

Basically the desired result would look like this:

[image]
Any help  would be extremely appreciated.

---

**EDIT**:

Added sample from input table
[image: Added sample from input table]

Comment: can you share samples from your input tables?

Comment: Place your query in a CTE or use a derived table - then you can filter based on the date diff column.  Note: convert the NULL value to a 0 in the inner query.

Comment: @lemon: i added some sample data. Hopefully this will suffice.

Comment: @Jeff: sorry, but i don't quite understand what you mean by the second part. You mention that I can filter based on the date diff column, but I need all the records and not a subset. 
I want to count the total duration in case the difference between the end date of the previous record and the begin date of the current record is less than 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

I’m sure there are better ways to accomplish this, but my purpose is fulfilled :-).

By using a CTE twice, in conjunction with a CASE function, I managed to group the data as needed.

The query looks like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT p.PersonId as PersonId, i.InquiryId as InquiryId, i.StartDate as StartDate, i.EndDate as EndDate, DATEDIFF(DAY, i.StartDate, i.EndDate) AS Duration, DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(i.EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY p.PersonId ORDER BY i.StartDate), i.StartDate) as DiffEndPrevRecStartCurrRec
   FROM Person p INNER JOIN
      Inquiry i on p.PersonId = i.PersonId
),
CTETWO AS
(
   SELECT PersonId, InquiryId, Duration, CASE WHEN DiffEndPrevRecStartCurrRec < 30 OR LEAD(DiffEndPrevRecStartCurrRec) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY StartDate) < 30 THEN 'X' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHER, InquiryId) END AS Grp
   FROM CTE
)
SELECT PersonId, SUM(Duration) AS 'Total duration'
FROM CTETWO
GROUP BY PersonId, Grp
ORDER BY PersonId
```

This is probably what @Jeff meant, but I didn't understand that at the time.

The result looks like this:

[image]